# Scala: change folder inside sbt

Tags: java, scala

I have a multi-module sbt project and I want to run a command in the root folder of my project; hence I need to do `cd ../..` .

I tried

```
import sys.process._
"cd ../..".!
```

But I get the following:

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "cd": error=2, No such file or directory
  at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
  at scala.sys.process.ProcessBuilderImpl$Simple.run(ProcessBuilderImpl.scala:69)
  at scala.sys.process.ProcessBuilderImpl$AbstractBuilder.run(ProcessBuilderImpl.scala:98)
  at scala.sys.process.ProcessBuilderImpl$AbstractBuilder.$bang(ProcessBuilderImpl.scala:112)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`cd` is not actually a program. It's a shell-internal that tells the shell to the `chdir` system call. Java doesn't even have a function to make the entire jvm to change its cwd (current working directory) (see [Changing the current working directory in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840190/changing-the-current-working-directory-in-java)) -- for Java file access, there is the `user.dir` property, but that's just a variable that Java functions look at.

One option is executing `sh -c "..."`, changing the directory *within* the forked process, like so:

```
import sys.process._
val cmd = "whatever you wanted to run"
s"sh -c 'cd ../..; $cmd'".!
```

But better still would be to use the http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/current/index.html#scala.sys.process.Process$ factories that take both a `command` and a `cwd`:

```
scala.sys.process.Process("your command here", new java.io.File("/some/dir"))
```

To use a relative dir, you might need to create the cwd from `user.dir` and "../.." and/or do something like [How to define a relative path in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14209085/how-to-define-a-relative-path-in-java)